# Installing Microsoft Office 2010 on Wine 1.4

Tags: installation, wine, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MS Word will not install: “pol_error”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187694/ms-word-will-not-install-pol-error)

Microsoft Office 2010 Professional Plus will not install because of windows codecs. I need help on installing dotnet20, msxml6 and corefonts using winetricks. It says it cannot validate or find the checksum. Please help me. I got this from [this article](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/how-to-install-microsoft-office-suite-2010-in-ubuntu-12-04-using-wine-1-5).

Comment: no, its the installer itself.

Comment: The question this is being duped to is indeed related to the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never had a problem installing Microsoft Office because I used PlayOnLinux.  It manages Wine versions and has installation scripts similar to wine tricks or Cross Over.

I think for the most part Libre Office does everything MS Office does, but I understand some times you need to install it.

Hope this helps.